# xlC compilation issue in AIX 6.0 environment

Tags: c, compiler-construction, aix, linkage, xlc

I'm compiling a set of .C files and trying to create object files on AIX 6.0 using xlC compiler version 9.0.  It's generating the following errors:

```
1540-1172 (S) More than one function "operator new" has non-C++ linkage.
1540-0424 (I) "operator new" is declared on line 92 of "/usr/vacpp/include/new".

1540-0121 (S) A template cannot have "C" linkage.

1540-0140 (S) The text "<" is unexpected.  "List" may be undeclared, ambiguous, or may require "typename" qualification.
```

Any kind of guidance or help would be appreciated.

```
$ xlC -qversion
C for AIX version 6.0.0.0
```

The compiler xlC is a C++ compiler only.  I've verified there is no extern 'C' around #include .  Please let me know the solution if anyone has worked on this.

Comment: This is pretty much useless as is.   You might consider showing the source code associated with the messages.

Comment: It is going to be hard to determine what is wrong from the minimal information provided.  It looks as though you might have: `extern "C" {` followed by `#include <new>` and `}` on three lines.  Alternatively, it might be that you're using a C compiler instead of a C++ compiler, but that is more likely to complain about the syntax of `operator new` than to allow it except for the fact that there are several declarations of `operator new` all with `extern "C"` linkage.

Answer (score 1):

That message happens when you try to overload functions inside extern "C"

extern "C"{

   struct A{};

   struct B{};

   void test(A arg);

   void test(B arg);

}

"q.cpp", line 5.9: 1540-1172 (S) More than one function "test" has non-C++ linkage.

"q.cpp", line 4.9: 1540-0424 (I) "test" is declared on line 4 of "q.cpp".

Comment: Thanks Catherine for your guidance.  I'll check if this applies to my code and update.

Comment: Catherine,   I've checked thoroughly and there are no such overloaded functions defined in extern "C" block... Please let me know if any other reasons... Thanks in advance